# Dragging connections from a storyboard to the app delegate

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, uistoryboard

I can't seem to find this anywhere, but I'm having issues trying to create reference outlets in my storyboard to my app delegate for `UIWindow` and `UIViewController`. The `UIViewController`s are from a `UISplitViewController`. From examples I've seen that use a xib file rather than a storyboard, the `IBOutlet`s seem to be made by "clicking and dragging".

I'm completely lost on the issue as Xcode won't let me drag any outlet into my app delegate. If you could help point out what I'm doing wrong, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: The AppDelegate is not connected to the storyboard unless you make it so yourself. Why do you want to make references to AppDelegate?

Comment: All the examples I saw did so such that the two UIViewControllers can communicate with each other without a mangled mess. And how would you propose I connect the AppDelegate to the storyboard? Thanks

Comment: Read this: http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1 . To share information, you could add things to appDelegate, but it might be better to use a singleton.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XCode and Story boards will typically only let you drag and connect outlets to view controllers. When using storyboards, select an item as the root view controller, and then do you communication and segues from there. If you are simply trying to map things to your storyboard, you should be able to find you to do something similar to:

```
UISplitViewController *splitViewController = (UISplitViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
```

If you have a general 'data sharing' class a singleton is a great way to always get a common instance of a class and ensure that all referencing classes are using the same information.